# When is dual-wielding beneficial?

Tags: combat, beyonder

According to the Rulebook section on "Multi-Weapon Fighting" (p. 139), any character can dual-wield any pair of weapons (as long as doing so is "not physically impossible", p. 136). The only caveats are:

1. the attack action takes 4 moments instead of 3, and
2. the two weapons take to-hit penalties of -2 and -7.

These are pretty severe caveats, but at the same time, a dual-wielder does get two attacks instead of one. It's not immediately clear whether, when, or how the benefits of dual-wielding outweigh the drawbacks.

In what circumstances does dual-wielding turn out to be better than single-wielding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### In terms of damage output, dual-wielding is only useful against targets with low Soak...

...and in some corner cases involving special preparation or *very* specific character stats.

To see why this is so, it's helpful to ignore the to-hit penalty at first and concentrate on the time issue. Since a two-weapon attack takes 4-m instead of 3, we can say that a two-weapon attack is equivalent to two one-weapon attacks at 75% of normal damage. In other words, a two-weapon strike does 150% damage. But remember that this is *damage*, not *wounds*! Both of those attacks are still reduced by the enemy's Soak, so against your 150% damage, the enemy effectively has *twice their normal Soak*. If their normal Soak is already respectable (say, 7 or more), then this doubling effect can be show-stopping.

In fact, the situation is even worse than that, because there is a third, unstated caveat:

3. You can't dual-wield large weapons.

You can two-hand a weapon up to your Size + 2, but with one hand you can only wield a weapon of your Size. As a result, you "lose" two points of damage when going from a two-handed to a one-handed weapon.

Let's run some numbers. Suppose you're well-specced for combat, as a Size(3) character with a choice between one Size(5) or two Size(3) axes. Your damage with the large axe will be 17/20/26/38, while the damage of each small axe, including the 75% factor, will be 11.25/13.5/18/27. If your target has a Soak of 7, equivalent to full-plate with no other bonuses, then your *wound output* will be 10/13/19/31 with the large axe, and 4.25/6.5/11/20 with each of the two small axes.

So you see that, at the minor and moderate success level, **dual-wielding is actually *detrimental*** in this case. At the major level, dual-wielding is slightly better, and then much better at the complete level. The result only gets worse if the enemy has a larger Soak, or if you're not as optimized for doing damage.

The situation becomes *even more grim* when you bring the to-hit penalty into the picture. The whopping -7 penalty for the off-hand weapon means that **your off-hand weapon will probably score one success level lower** than your single-weapon strike would. For example, if our Size(3) warrior above consistently scored in the middle of the major success range with one weapon, then dual-wielding would "decompose" this major success into one major and one moderate. Looking back at the numbers, a single-weapon major success would do 19 wounds, while a two-weapon major + moderate would do 17.5. So dual-wielding *once again* turns out to be worse than single-wielding. This "decomposing" effect **only** vanishes if your average to-hit roll is 13, 14, 15, 23, 24, 25, or 33 or higher. (In fact, if your average roll is 1, 2, 6, 7, 16, 17, 26, or 27, then **both** of your two-weapon attacks will be one success level lower on average!)

**In summary**, dual-wielding is actively harmful to your damage output unless:

- the enemy has very low Soak, or
- the enemy has middling Soak and your average roll falls in a specific range, or
- you are an unstoppable warrior-god who consistently rolls complete successes.

### That said, special preparation can make dual-wielding less useless.

Since you do get two attacks instead of one, any damage bonuses and per-attack effects *will* be magnified when you are dual-wielding. This *can* be devastating, if you have the time, foresight, Fatigue, and good fortune to activate these effects before you start fighting. Useful effects include combat-related Stunts; the Shadow Power "Negate Armor", which allows a few of your attacks to ignore Soak; the Emotion Power "Allied Attack", which grants +1 damage on each attack per nearby ally; and a few Barrier Abilities from the Body and Physic trees.